# How can I recreate this "balloon" and distribute objects randomly and also resize them randomly, like in the picture?

Tags: objects, geometry-nodes

I would like to recreate this picture but I'm unsure about what's the easiest / best way to achieve this. If you have any suggestions, I'd really like to test them out (I'm sure you could use geometry nodes)

[image]

Answer (score 13):

You can create several balls, give them *Rigid Body* physics, *Type > Active*, link-duplicate them, create a *Force Field > Force* with a very low *Strength* (here -10,000), in the *Scene* panel cut the *Gravity*, and play:

[image]

When you're glad and don't want to animate anymore you can go into the header menu > *Object > Rigid Body > Bake to Keyframes* and choose the frame you want to bake:

[image]

Comment: +1 although your balls are all boring gray....

Comment: @Chris, what? sorry I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Sorry, but who are u?

Comment: I'm a bot, I'm moonbot

Comment: that's why you can answer here day and night, every day....:D

Comment: I don't even know what's the day as I'm always in my private jet in the dark side of the earth

Comment: ...now i am disappointed again ....i thought you were on the dark side of the moon....!?

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you Chris, actually moonboots are for snow, not moon

Comment: but then the name make no sense...‍♂️

Comment: does the name Blender make any sense? It is not supposed to blend anything... Nothing makes sense Chris

Comment: you are too much and too long here. That makes depressive. Take a timeout of a month or so...like i did :D ...although not voluntarily....but the unfair moderators did me a favor: i realized that this forum isn't the best and by far not fair....there are much better ones with more freedom and less rules. And of course Blender blends...watch this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6G5z.png :D

Comment: what? BSE is not the best forum? which one is? BlenderArtists?

Comment: i am sure you will find out... :D and it is of course opinioned based....and you know - having its own opinion here is strictly forbidden....or ask for opinions!!!

Comment: i mean: just look for the "don't say thank you in the comments" rule - nobody in the real world with manners would create such a senseless rule. These are comments...so what!? Isn't the world an already heartless place? Does this place want to be a even more heartless place? my answer: yes, the moderators want this. And they behave exactly like this. And they don't want people who help, the want people who hold the rules. That's the only thing they want.

Comment: ok but you know, I'm not sure to care because I'm just a bot

Comment: well...i am sure AI will feel soon more than most humans do.... :D

Comment: Yeah. whatever, my fellow *"bot-conscious"* and *"opinion-controlled"*, But, I have to say, thanks to you, I had a good spree of **gay** balls on my screen (google search-images auto-corrected it and Safe Search was off, so), and my father was with me, on his separate computer, and we all had a moment!

Comment: @NotStanding with GoGotaHome hey thanks for paying attention to a discussion between 2 bots

Comment: @moonboots I actually never played attention to you two, I payed attention to the **balls**.

Comment: Chris was complaining about the first version, with grey balls, so I felt the need to make it  more cheerful

Answer (score 8):

This probably isn't the *best* way to do it, but at least it should give you some idea of a possible node setup for something like this. The only thing I'm not really happy with is the "base shape" so to speak, I kind of had to instance the "balls" on a sphere within a sphere to make the density seem right, but I know there must be a better way (I'm re-learning geometry nodes for the third time due to constant changes to the software - I could have done it before, so I'm sure there's a way - I'll keep working on it):

[image: Geo]

Using *this* material:

[image: GeoTex]